# Strange URLs when culture is enable

Tags: kentico, kentico-mvc, kentico-12

I am running Kentico 12.0.26 MVC.

When adding links via the inline widget editor (MediumEditor), the final URL that gets generated has a strange URL path, which is not a pretty URL for SEO.

```
http://localhost/cmsctx/pv/administrator/culture/en-US/wg/54e1b893-56a5-455b-9f89-37433f2f4365/readonly/0/ea/1/h/98d86f48b5376d0f10eb44df47afb782729ba12751defe6a5ce98c918950785e/-/products/Tube-Pipe-Systems/FL-WELD-P-ORB?uh=b0542cb25017b58c3ebde4855543bcea15269abf4d7458251db4ff128f2feb30&administrationdomain=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost
```

Not all links have this, but when this links where added, it was using the clean relative URL of the page, I think maybe after enabeling the Kentico culture feature, they somehow got update like that, but not all links got affected. I am still not entirely sure at what point to they get updated like that.

I also notice that links that are added via the page type editor (CKEditor) are fine and don't seem to run into this issue.

Please advise, thanks

Comment: Do not put tags in the title

Comment: Changed link to code for readability

Comment: [BillDo168](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1089188) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66257962) saying "Please check this link to fix this issue:
https://devnet.kentico.com/articles/how-to-fix-links-inserted-via-a-wysiwig-editor-in-kentico-12
When create Widget Static html, i follow this link: https://diger74.net/static-html-widget"